# To push data into a nested object in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm building an statistical system that when an user clicks a link, the python server sends date and time data to MongoDB. For example, if now is "2020-11-10, 11:41:20" then in MongoDB, there should be

```
{
  _id: "1123",
  time: {
    2020: {
      11: {
        10: ["11:41:20"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then, if another user clicks the link, say the time is "2020-11-13, 10:23:00", I want to push the data into already existing document above. The result should be

```
{
  _id: "1123",
  time: {
    2020: {
      11: {
        10: ["11:41:20"],
        13: ["10:23:00"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I've been doing is get all the data into a python object and manually insert new time data to the object, and update the whole document. is there any neat way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is a smart design to use dynamic field names. You would need to use again and again `$objectToArray`, `$arrayToObject` and `$reduce` operators. Apart from that you should **never** store date/time values as string, use proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use dot notation with $push operator, if the parent object not existing, the mongodb will create automatically.

```js
> db.test.findOne()
{
  "_id" : "1123",
  "time" : {
    "2020" : {
      "11" : {
        "10" : [
          "11:41:20"
        ],
        "13" : [
          "10:23:00"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
> db.test.updateOne({_id: '1123'}, {
  $push: {
    'time.2020.11.14': '23:00:00',
    'time.2020.11.13': '23:01:00'
  }
})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.test.findOne()
{
  "_id" : "1123",
  "time" : {
    "2020" : {
      "11" : {
        "10" : [
          "11:41:20"
        ],
        "13" : [
          "10:23:00",
          "23:01:00"
        ],
        "14" : [
          "23:00:00"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/